# How to temporarily change output path when precompiling assets, Sprockets / Rails assets pipeline, 3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to update this code to work with the released Rails 3.1.0:

```
  # temporarily set the static assets location from public/assets to our spec directory
  ::Rails.application.assets.static_root = Rails.root.join("spec/javascripts/generated/assets")

  ::Rake.application['assets:clean'].invoke
  ::Rake.application['assets:precompile'].invoke
```

Now that Sprockets::Environment#static_root has been removed, what's the best way temporarily change the sprockets output directory?

Edit:  Also I'd like to be able to clean the assets in my custom output directory :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `config.assets.prefix`, but this will still put the assets in the public directory (see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/sprockets/assets.rake#L49) for the rake task, which joins the `public_path` and the prefix).

In your case, this should work:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.prefix = "../spec/javascripts/generated/assets"
Rails.application.config.assets.manifest = File.join(Rails.public_path, config.assets.prefix)
```

I had to specify the manifest path because of the weird load order of the sprockets railtie. Without doing it, it gets stuck at `public/assets`, which doesn't exist and blows up the rake task. YMMV.

Side note: I tried this in the development environment at first, but the `config.assets.prefix` refused to change. I suspect putting `config.assets.enabled` to `true` would have fixed this, but I haven't got around to testing it yet.

As a bonus, the `assets:clean` works perfectly with this solution (you can see it for yourself [in the rake task](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/sprockets/assets.rake#L83))

Comment: I really love this kind of question which give me the perfect excuse to take a dive in the rails source :-)

Comment: This will work soon in Rails 4 once this PR is merged: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/136. Until then, you can use https://github.com/johnnyshields/sprockets-rails.